# sql want to count one column only if another column is ok

Tags: mysql, count

I have a db like this:

```
id  name   job   payment
1   susan  job1  no
2   rob    job2  no
3   mike   job3  yes
4   bob    job2  yes
```

I need to get the number of persons group by job, but only if they have yes in the payment.
I have done something like this:

```
SELECT job, count(*) AS job FROM database GROUP BY job
```

The result is the count of persons with the same job, but I don't know how to check the other column (payment) and only if it is "yes" make the count.

Hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: `where payment = "yes" ` ?

Comment: @Chefuss . . . What do you want the result set to look like?  Please edit the question and show that as a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `SUM` and condition:

```
SELECT job, SUM(payment = 'yes') AS job_cnt
FROM database
GROUP BY job;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=757cc83e5a3e9910a57939e55130c39a)**

Output:

```
┌───────┬─────────┐
│ job   │ job_cnt │
├───────┼─────────┤
│ job1  │       0 │
│ job2  │       1 │
│ job3  │       1 │
└───────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you Lukasz!! you have solved all of my problems in less than a second!! thank you!!! This is working great!!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the where clause as follows

```
SELECT job, count(*) AS job
FROM database
WHERE payment="yes"
GROUP BY job
```